# How do I specify the stylesheets in my project are compiled/loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have a file in my folder `theme/skins/default.css` and I have another file called `/style.css`. I want the styles from `default.css` to be added to my `application.css` after the styles in `style.css`. Aside from manually copying them, how do I do it? Basically all the stylesheets in my `theme/skins/` folder, I would like to be added to my `application.css` file after my `style.css`.

In other words, I would like the styles in my `theme/skins/default.css` to override the files in my `style.css` where they do exist.

How do I go about doing that within the constraints of the Rails 3.2 asset pipeline?

**Edit 1**

Note that I tried this:

```
/*
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require "theme/skins/default"
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

And that doesn't render it in the correct order.

When I do a view source on my page, this is what I see:

```
<link href="/assets/theme/skins/default.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/theme/slick.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/theme/style.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The assets pipeline compiler respects the order you required the files on the manifest. The problem is that you have `require_tree .` above everything (thus, your specific require gets ignored because it was required before).

Try this:

```
/*
 *= require 'theme/skins/style'
 *= require "theme/skins/default"
 *= require_tree . (this will ignore files already required)
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

EDIT: adding a link to the manifest doc https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives